# Having an issue with puppeteer and a selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, selector, puppeteer

So I'm running into a couple of odd errors here at work and was wondering if anyone of you would have some insight...

My script logs on to a website and fills out a field. This field allows input from a selection of predetermined values. Here's the line of code in question: `await page.select('.sc-1v3iu6p-0 > .sc-1luxqst-0 > div:nth-child(3) > .sc-1q14n20-0:nth-child(1) > .sc-cSHVUG', value):`

Now, most of this time the script runs fine, but once in awhile it doesn't and I get this error
**Error: Evaluation failed: Error: Element is not a  element.
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:15**

Since it usually works, the element is a select element.

Any ideas as to why this happens or maybe how to fix it, would be greatly appreciated. I'd share my code but since it's for work I don't believe I should. I can provide some additional information though!

Thank you for your time

Comment: I think sometimes because of network issue the line execute before the selector prepared. Did you try waiting for the selector first? like: await page. `await page.waitForSelector(selector, { visible: true })`

Comment: I have with other slectors I occasionally have a problem with. Whenever a problem does arise the waitFor usually times out :/